# Zend Log logging username for every log event

Tags: zend-framework

I'm using Zend 1.12.

I'm wondering if this solution would work. I would like to add the username or userid for the current logged in user.

In my Bootstrap file I have:

```
protected function _initLogger(){
    $dt=new DateTime();
    $writer = new Zend_Log_Writer_Stream(ROOT_DIR.'/logs/log'.$dt->format('Y-m-d').'.txt','a+');
    $logger = new Zend_Log($writer);
    Zend_Registry::set('logger', $logger);
}
```

I'm not sure about this but if I change it to:

```
protected function _initLogger(){
        $dt=new DateTime();
        $writer = new Zend_Log_Writer_Stream(ROOT_DIR.'/logs/log'.$dt->format('Y-m-d').'.txt','a+');
        $format = '%uid% %username% %timestamp% %priorityName% (%priority%): %message%' . PHP_EOL;
        $writer->setFormatter(new Zend_Log_Formatter_Simple($format));
        $logger = new Zend_Log($writer);
        $session=new Zend_Session_Namespace('Default');
        if(isset($session->user)){
            $logger->setEventItem('username', $user->username);
            $logger->setEventItem('uid', $user->userid);

        }
        Zend_Registry::set('logger', $logger);
}
```

Would this work when mutliple users are working simultaniously? As far as I understand Zend_Registry is application wide (static) and therefore works over sessions.

Does anyone have an alternative to this?

Comment: Your comment about `Zend_Registry` is a bit unclear, but items stored in the registry do not persist between requests, if that's what you are thinking. That doesn't look like it would affect the code you posted though.

Comment: @TimFountain, Thank you for your comment. It was not clearly stated in the comments of the Zend documentation. If it it request based it will work I suppose.